# Use mgetty to answer a call and press a key

Tags: serial-port, modem, getty, gsm

I bought a GSM shield for the Raspberry Pi (version 1, B) and a SIM card to join the proper cellular network. I use `mgetty` to react to my call, like this:

```
mgetty conf
```

which works just fine and the script executes once I call the RPi:

```
port ttyAMA0
  speed 9600
  post-init-chat "" ATH0 OK ATS0=0 OK AT+CLIP=1 OK
  rings 2
  answer-chat "" ATH0
  cnd-program /home/pi/caller.sh
```

The thing I want to do is not only executing the script above (which is currently a dummy script), but also answer the phone call and press a specific button (press <kbd>*</kbd>).

Interestingly, there is quite some documentation across the web, how to use `mgetty` as a dialin modem, but I couldn't find a way to answer the call and send a key. Even this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272756/how-to-configure-mgetty-to-answer-and-dial-6-on-ring) is unanswered and I cannot post a comment to ping the author of the question...